# Probability formula - binomial probability

Tags: probability

A coin is tossed n times.
What is a formula that gives the probability (P), of getting only tails?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a fair coin, the probability of getting tails on one toss is $\frac{1}{2}$.  Since the tosses are independent, the probability you want is $(\frac{1}{2})^n$.